# Basic Steps in reading Excel files into matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsread

```
>> [NUM,TXT,RAW]=xlsread('C:\Users\Lincoln Wachn\Google Drive\Summer time\Book1')
??? Error using ==> xlsread at 219
XLSREAD unable to open file C:\Users\Lincoln Wachn\Google Drive\Summer
time\Book1.
File C:\Users\Lincoln Wachn\Google Drive\Summer time\Book1.xls not found.
```

This is the error that I have received when I try to read a simple Excel file into MATLAB.

---

This is a snapshot of the spreadsheet I would like to load in.

[image: Book1 image]

Could guide me the basic know-how to extract these data? I have looked through the other questions pertaining to reading Excel files into MATLAB, but I am still very confused.
I ultimately wish to extract the file below for my project using the same method.

[image: Image 2 for my project]

The second image shows the data I have to extract which I could not do.  Its file type seems to be different, it is comma separated values file which is not `xls`. Hence, I am also confuse about whether different file type prevents extraction of data.

Comment: "File not found" Is this unclear in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty obvious.  It says `File not found`.  Make sure the file that you want to load in is placed in the same directory as the one referenced in `xlsread`.  Also, to read in comma-separated value files, use the [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) function.

Comment: Hi rayryeng, may I know the difference between xls and csv type? Any source that I can read up on. Thanks you!

Comment: `xls` is a proprietary Microsoft format so you would need software like Excel (or MATLAB and R) to read it.  `csv` can be made completely on your own.  Each column is separated by a **comma**, and each row is separated by a carriage return.  Very easy format.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values